# Merge source from one SVN repository into another?

Tags: git, svn

I'm very familiar and right at home with git, but I recently started working at a larger organization where svn is used, and I'm somewhat unfamiliar with it. In the current project I'm working on, we have two separate svn repositories, one for test/development and one for production. One of my coworkers made some hotfixes right in production, admitting he shouldn't but did anyway. So now it's my job to merge his changes from the production repo into the test/development repo and then push the merged source back out to the prod repo.

How do I do this using SVN?

In git I would:

```
# in development repo
git remote add prod SOME_URI_HERE
git fetch prod
git merge prod/master
# resolve conflicts, if any...
git push prod master
```

What's the equivalent workflow/thought process in SVN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your *test/development* branch of svn branch is **TEST_DEV_URL**, and the hotfix's URL of svn branch is **HOTFIX_URL**.

First, you should `checkout` hotfix branch:

```
svn checkout HOTFIX_URL hotfix_name
```

Second, `cd` *hotfix_name* svn working directory, and merge your test branch to hotfix:

```
svn mergeinfo TEST_DEV_URL hotfix_name # test merge
svn merge TEST_DEV_URL hotfix_name
```

# Third, resolve conflicts, if any...

Last, commit your merges:

```
svn commit -m ""
```